# Who features in, or makes, a "gratuitous cameo," in Deadpool?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Having watched Deadpool for the third time this afternoon I realised that I couldn't identify the "gratuitous cameo" referred to in the film's opening credits. So: which character is this "credit" referring to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It was Stan Lee.

From [here](http://screenrant.com/deadpool-easter-eggs-movie/?view=all) (among [other sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=deadpool%20"gratuitous%20cameo")):

> As always, Stan Lee delivers on the promise of a “Gratuitous Cameo,” but his appearance in Deadpool, it’s safe to say, is unlike any other before. This time around, Lee can be seen DJ-ing at the strip club that Wade and Weasel head to in order to track down Vanessa.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered that; I saw him, of course, but discounted him from consideration given his (almost) obligatory appearance in Marvel-related films.

Comment: Worth noting that Stan Lee wasn't involved in creating Deadpool

Comment: @Mike: to be fair to the MCU movies at least, they tend to have comedy threaded through them, rather than having a single comedy sidekick in the mold of Deadpool’s Weasel.