# What exactly is Venom (2018)'s relationship with Marvel, Disney, and the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, venom-2018, sonys-marvel-universe

As many know, the rights to certain Marvel film properties are not owned by Disney, but by Sony Pictures.   In particular, this includes the characters of Spider-Man and Venom.   Now, we all know that Spider-Man is currently part of the MCU under special agreement between Sony and Disney.

Yet it is claimed that Venom is not.   In particular,

> There's no mention any other part of the MCU in *Venom (2018)*.   And I've seen the argument on Youtube that the lines between Brock and Skirth in *Venom* stating that for there to be aliens is "completely crazy" means it can't possibly be the MCU since alien interference on Earth is very much public knowledge in the MCU (The Battles of New York and Wakanda, Thor, etc.)

On the other hand:

> The title cards on *Venom* state that it is "in association with Marvel" and there is a cameo by Stan Lee, which is very much in keeping with MCU films.

So,

## What exactly is the relationship between *Venom (2018)*, Marvel, Disney, and the MCU?

Comment: Somebody please correct if I should be talking about Columbia and not Sony.   It's all pretty fuzzy for me.

Comment: Stan Lee appears in _Marvel_ films not necessarily those in the MCU. See _Deadpool_, for example.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:   Regarding Stan Lee -- that's part of an answer.   Point is, typical movie going could easily be confused by this.

Comment: “The title cards on Venom state that it is in association with Marvel” — I think they say that on the X-Men movies too. You know when you’re really into someone, and you want to hang out with them, and dress like them, and basically be them, but all your attempts seem to fall flat, and they never return your calls? The relationship is like that.

Comment: Stan Lee appears in everything - even DC films (Teen Titans Go to the Movies)

Comment: Everyone, just because I point out some things that might lead people to think it's part of the MCU, doesn't mean I don't get that they don't necessarily mean that.   That's fodder for an answer, not a reason to criticize the question.

Comment: Related question from sister site: [Does the upcoming film with Venom take place in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88335/does-the-upcoming-film-with-venom-take-place-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe)

Answer (score 9):

## It is not part of the MCU

> In a live Facebook interview with French website, AlloCiné (that we managed to transcribe) Feige revealed that we won’t be seeing Holland and Hardy go toe-to-toe in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.
>
> When asked about a potential appearance Feige explained:
>
> **“For now, there is NO plan for Venom in the MCU. It’s a Sony Project.”**
>
> <sub>[Screen Geek, Kevin Feige Says There Are No Plans For VENOM In The Marvel Cinematic Universe](https://www.screengeek.net/2017/06/13/kevin-feige-no-plans-venom-marvel-cinematic-universe/)</sub>

And if [this transcribed school Q/A](https://pastebin.com/YdLUxFJD) is to be believed the Russo brothers have said the same thing on a different occasion.

> Student: I have two- is the new venom movie going to be in the MCU?
>
> Russo: No that’s a Sony property

In fact Sony has stated that *Venom* was meant to be the start of a new series of films set in "Sony's Marvel Universe".

> Following Spider-Man: Homecoming, which will be released in the coming weeks, Sony has plans to release a spinoff film focusing on one of Spider-Man’s most recognizable villains, Venom. There are also plans for Silver Sable and Black Cat spinoffs, all tied into the Spider-Man world that Sony owns the rights to.
>
> When Sony confirmed yesterday that Hardy would be playing Venom, the studio used an interesting phrase to define the universe that the film would belong to: Sony’s Marvel Universe.
>
> <sub>[Polygon, Sony’s Marvel Universe won’t actually connect to the Marvel Universe](https://www.polygon.com/2017/5/20/15666722/spider-man-venom-sony-marvel-cinematic-universe)</sub>

> @SonyPictures: Tom Hardy is Eddie Brock in #Venom, the upcoming film from Sony’s Marvel Universe releasing October 5, 2018 – production starts this fall.
>
> <sub>[Twitter, @SonyPictures](https://twitter.com/SonyPictures/status/865629713225572352)</sub>

And to be clear Stan Lee being in a film has nothing to do with the Marvel Cinematic Universe just Marvel in general. For example, see the X-men Cinematic Universe with [*Deadpool*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120710/58193) and [*Deadpool 2*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187791/58193) for some recent examples.